# Maximum likelihood function for time series model

Tags: regression, time-series, maximum-likelihood, autoregressive

Given Linear Regression model
$$
y_i =\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i  + \epsilon_i 
$$
where $\epsilon_i \sim N(0,\sigma ^2)$, joint density will be  > $\prod f(\epsilon_i)$ since they're all independent. However, in other models like AR , MA they are dependant on the previous value.

AR Model $ x_t=  \sum_{j=1}^p \phi x_{t-j} + \omega$ where $\omega \sim N(0,\sigma^2)$.

I know we will use the rule of  $p(y|x)=p(x,y)/p(x)$ to get the joint density, but I can't get my head around how to can do it recursively.

I have read this paper "http://mayoral.iae-csic.org/timeseries_insead/handout3_armaestimation_irfs_arch.pdf"
and i have some questions :

$X2|(X1=x1)  \sim N(c+\phi x1,\sigma^2)$ => i know mean and variane for x1 , but not sure how did they get this conditional distrubtion?

then they mentioned that the joint distribution for $x1 , x2 ,x3$

$f x3 ,x2 ,x1 = fx3|x2,x1 * fx2|x1 * fx1$
this makes since , but then they mentioned that over $t$ observation the equation will be

$fx_T , x_{T-1} .. x_1 = fx_1  *  _{t=2} ^ T fx_t|x_{t-1}$

again not sure how  this adds up !

Comment: Are you asking about obtaining the joint distribution of $x_1,x_2,...$ in an AR model?

Comment: yes , but I'd like to know all steps involved not the final equation

Comment: Hi: See andrew harvey's text: "econometric analysis of time series". he has a lot of good examples along with the steps of how to estimate time series models with regressors. AR and MA are covered more in box, jenkins and reinsel but the same sort of concepts apply.

Comment: In your last question, the authors assume that the time series forms a Markov chain. That is, $x_t$ is independent of $x_{t-2}$ given $x_{t-1}$.

Comment: @mhdadk if you refer to the linear regression model, yes the white noise is iid and follows Markov chain . However, in the AR model, $x_t$ is dependant on $x_{t-1}$

Comment: That's not what a Markov chain is. A Markov chain is not the same as i.i.d random variables. Please see [this](http://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter11/11_2_1_introduction.php) for more info.